Cannot upload license file to Netscaler
I am logged into the NetScaler, release 13.1.37.183 FIPS, via the GUI as a superuser. When I try to import a new license file to the NetScaler a get an error: "Not authorized to execute this command". I can use the CLI to upload the license. Has anyone else run across this and fix it?
I has also tried listing all roles to my account incase I missed something that superuser couldn't do.
